# How to replace the default domain on wp get shortlink

Tags: php

```
 <?php echo wp_get_shortlink(); ?>
```

When using this line you will get **mydomain.com/?p=1**. I was wondering if I can change my domain like **myalternatedomain.com/?p=1** while using this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the link returned by `wp_get_shortlink()` using [`get_shortlink` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_shortlink/).

```
add_filter( 'get_shortlink', 'cyb_replace_domain_shortlink' );
function cyb_replace_domain_shortlink( $shortlink ) {
    return str_replace( 'mydomain.com', 'myalternatedomain.com', $shortlink );
}
```